# Get Logical Volumes Group name in legacy grub

Tags: linux, boot, centos, grub, rescue

I am currently in GNU GRUB v0.97 Restore mode and I have CentOS 6.5 installed with /boot partition separated and rest of filesystem is in Volume Group. But, I don't remember volume group name, is there a way to read it from somewhere? I have mounted /boot partition successfully and I am stuck at loading kernel, because I don't remember name of LVG so I can't mount filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo -s ;

## vgs; lvs; pvs

## exit

user@centos ~:$
From the above sequence  you can get the full lowdown on the entire group and all its members..

Comment: Sir, this wont work because i am in gnu brub RESTORE mode. I didnt boot os yet, because filesystem root is on logical volume i dont remember name. so my command prompt looks like:    grub>